# Cannot boot to NetInstall image

Tags: server.app, netboot

I have one Mac Mini with Server installed and the NetInstall service On. It looks like this:

[image: Server]

I plugged an ethernet cable into this Mini, and plugged the other end into a MacBook.  I'm now trying to boot the MacBook to the netboot image.

I tried holding down Option during boot; the only option I see is the local HDD.  I tried holding down N during boot; it does not find anything.  What else to I have to do to make this work?

I tried turning on the DHCP server on the Mini but that doesn't seem to provide addresses to either machine.  Not sure why auto-assigned addresses wouldn't work for this though, since this is just an isolated ad-hoc network.

If this works I will add a network switch so I can do 5-10 Macs at once.  So I'm not looking for an easier offline solution that will only let me do one at a time.

Comment: Auto-assigned = 169.254.0.0/16? Do you run a second DHCP server (i.e a router) in your network?

Comment: Yes and no.  Is a router required for this to work?  This is just two macs connected by an ethernet cable, not connected to a larger network

Comment: Get a small switch [like this Netgear FS105](https://www.amazon.com/NETGEAR-ProSAFE-FS105NA-5-Port-Ethernet/dp/B00002EQCW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1494631422&sr=8-1&keywords=netgear+FS105) and use 2 ethernet cables.

Comment: A router isn't required unless the they're in different network subnets. A direct ethernet connection will work but you have to configure/enable DHCP on the NetBoot server. Did you configure a pool of address for DHCP? I've never tried this with auto-assigned addresses...

If you have a DHCP server available elsewhere on the network then you don't have to enable it in Server.app.

Comment: If all else fails I start looking at packet traces next. BSDP (NetBoot) uses bootp option 43 so you can filter with something like "bootp.option.type eq 43" in Wireshark.